# ImageMagick, passenger, rails, attachement_fu doesn't resize

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, attachment-fu, ruby-on-rails

So after a couple of months of development today I am finaly deploying!
(WOOHOO great day).
But i am stuck with a problem I can't seem to fix:

First of all in development all is working perfectly.
In deployment on my server it isn't though!. I use attachment_fu and i
am able to upload
pictures but the pictures are not resizing.

There is nothing in the production log or in de apache error log.
I am using ImageMagick with Mini_magick, Passenger and Attachement_fu.
So I can upload (no problem) but for some reason the images don't
resize! like i told attachement fu to do.

Also i read and Googled my ass off and found some thing about Apache export
you need to add or something. But so far i don't know what to do at this
point!

Thanxs in advance for any advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIR Image Magick requires some native packages to be installed on the server. I guess libmagick6-dev or sth like that.

Try this, run Rails console on your production and type ImageMagick. If it has all the necessary dependencies you should see no error.

Comment: Ohw you are smart! I never thought of that ! 
Ok so after installing irb I got the following:
<code>
>> MiniMagick <br/>
=> MiniMagick
</code>

so that is as expected.

Comment: YES it works now. I have really no idea what i did .. But just to help somebody else: just install all your gems en imagemagick rmagick etc. again! (and again) until it works .. :(

Comment: I'm glad I could help. The problem was with native extensions. Reinstalling them triggered rebuilding extensions.